# Converting .tex to .docx file with a certain document class using pandoc

Tags: pandoc, msword

Extreme **TeX** and **LaTeX* newcomer, I am trying to convert a `.tex` to a `.docx` (Word) document.

I am using the pandoc command line utility and got so far as converting the document, i.e., by doing something like `pandoc tex-file.tex -s -o word-file.docx`. That worked, but didn't seem to recognize the document class, which is a file in the same directory with a name like `class.cls`.

When I (clumsily) tried something like `pandoc tex-file.tex -s -o --variable documentclass='class-cls' word-file.docx`, an error was returned: `openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`.

Can you point me in the right direction for converting a `.tex` to a `.docx` file with a certain document class using pandoc (or, if recommended, another tool)?

Comment: Welcome! I've used tex4ht, even with a custom class. However, you may need to adapt the document for it to work properly and will certainly need to clean up the result. Using this method, I convert first to ODT and then export DOCX from LibreOffice.

Comment: as @cfr said, you should have better luck with `tex4ht`, because it supports custom LaTeX commands and packages. You will probably need some configuration, I can look at it if you provide a `mwe` and your class.